# Flask: How to set a conditional within an image's url

Tags: python, flask, backend, server-side, templatetags

What is the way to do this in Flask?

I have the URL `/ninja/<color>`
which renders ninja.html
and if color is not red, blue, purple, or orange, it sets the variable color to "notvalid"

and depending on the color, I want this image to change in the template.

```
 <center><img src={{url_for('static', filename=
      {% if color=="blue" %}
        'leonardo.png'
      {% elif color=="purple" %}
        'donatello.png'
      {% elif color=="red" %}
        "raphael.png"
      {% elif color=="orange" %}
        ''michelangelo.png"
      {% elif color=="notvalid" %}
        "notapril.png"
      {% else %}
        'tmnt.png'
      {% endif %}
      )}}></center>
```

But it shows me an invalid syntax error, 'unexpected %'

Comment: `''michelangelo.png"` - is this a typo? if not, this would cause a syntax error

Comment: You should make an effort to conform to either single or double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily compute that before you call `render_template`

```
images = {
 "blue": "leonardo.png",
 "purple": "donatello.png",
 ...
}

render_template("template", image=images["color"], ...)
```

then just do `<img src={{url_for('static', filename=image)/>` - Jinja is pretty powerful, but it doesn't let you do *anything*.

Comment: There is clearly a typo here which causes that syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the above template

```
''michelangelo.png" #you should use either single or double quotes but not both.
```